# jQuery scroll down 100%, re-position element to top: 0, causes flicker

Tags: jquery

I have two elements. The 1st one uses 100% height of the browser, and is positioned `fixed`. The 2nd element has a position `top: 100%;` to appear beneath the 1st fixed one.

I set this up, so the 2nd element can slide over the 1st one, when scrolling. No problems so far.

But now, I want to `.remove()` the 1st element, after I scrolled to the 2nd. So the 2nd replaces the 1st element.

In order to do this, I have to re-position the 2nd element to `top: 0`, instead of the initial `top: 100%`. I then also have to `scrollTop(0)` in order to see the top of the 2nd element, because it got re-positioned.

However, this last step causes the page to flicker (9 times out of 10)! How can I solve this?

Is there a cleaner way to achieve this?

UPDATE: the flicker only occurs in Safari so far, Chrome does it flawlessly. And in Firefox it doesn't even work.. This is just basic jQuery, right??

Here's my jQuery code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($('body').scrollTop() >= $('body').height()) {
        $('#elem-2').css({top: '0'});
        $('body').scrollTop(0);
        $('header').css({position: 'fixed'});  // header inside #elem-2
        $('#elem-1').remove();
    }
});
```

And the CSS:

```
#elem-1 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    background-color: #00a1b1;
}

#elem-2 {
    position: relative;
    top: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
}

header {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 130px;
    display: block;
}
```

Anyone?

Comment: can you mock up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.com) or show some code?

Comment: 'header' refers to the header html5 element. No `#` or `.` missing there.